# Defining custom type wrongly?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the following code, I'm trying to define a custom type:

```
public class WindowPosition
{
    public static WindowPosition Below;
    public static WindowPosition Right;
}

private void ChildWindow(Form Form, WindowPosition Position)
{
    Form.Location = new Point(
        Position == WindowPosition.Right ? this.Location.X + this.Width : 0,
        Position == WindowPosition.Below ? this.Location.Y + this.Height : 0
    );

    Form.Show();
}

private void buttonNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChildWindow(new New(), WindowPosition.Below);
}
```

The code is supposed to make the `New` form open directly *below* the main form - but instead it's opening here:

[image: a]

`New`'s `StartPosition` is set to `Manual`.

I think I'm defining the type improperly. How can I properly define it?

Or otherwise what is the problem, or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want an Enum, not a class.

```
enum WindowPosition {
     Right,
     Bottom
}
```

Reference it like so: `WindowPosition.Right`

What you're doing is declaring a class, then saying it has 2 static members of the same type as it, which isn't wholly unreasonable for some different applications, but it won't work for this.

The reason it doesn't work with your code is because neither of them are assigned anything, and so they both return `null`, which would make `WindowPosition.Right == WindowPosition.Left` return true.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that works perfectly! I'll accept as soon as I can :) Your explanation is appreciated too.

Comment: Good luck with your coding!